# REACT, my javascript code slows down when certain functions run

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a react app, and everytime you click the button, or on page load the green square moves randomly, but everytime the Move randomly is clicked it runs the enem() function it works, as expected. One problem is that when you click the button multiple times everything will start to noticeably slow down any way around this?

```
const { useRef } = React








const Main = props => {
   const textInput = useRef()
   const EN = useRef()
   const move = useRef()
   var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1320)
   const [change, setchange] = React.useState(1)
   
  const cursors = {
    pointerEvents: "none",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    width: "20PX",
    height: "20PX",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    position: "fixed",        
    transform:"translate3d(-10px,-10px,15px)",
    
  };
  
  
    const enemy = { 
    zIndex: "-1",
    borderRadius: "20%",
    width: "30PX",
    height: "30PX",
    backgroundColor: "green",
    position: "absolute",
    left: "${change}px",


  };
  

  
  
  const borders = {
    width: "1300px",
    height: "620px",
    backgroud: "#ccc",
    border: "4px solid #333",
    position: "absolute",
    right: "500px"
  }
  
  const testi = {
    background: "steelblue",
    color: "white",
    padding: "1.5rem"
    
  }
  
  function enem() {
    
    setchange(change + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1320))
     EN.current.style.left = randomize + "px"
   
    console.log("FSDF")
    
   
    

    
    
    
   
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    

    
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) =>{
      textInput.current.style.top =   event.clientY  + 'px' 
      textInput.current.style.bottom =  event.clientX  + 'px'
      textInput.current.style.left = event.clientX + 'px' 
      textInput.current.style.right = event.clientY  + 'px' 
        console.log(event.clientY)
      
      if(textInput.current.style.right == "1320px"){
      console.log("help")
      
    }
     
    })
    
    
    console.log(textInput.current.style.left)
  });
  
  
    
 
  
  return (
   
        
      
  
    <div  style={borders} >
    <div ref={textInput} style={cursors}></div>   
      <div style={enemy} ref={EN}></div>
      <div className={"pe"} ref={move}></div>
      <button onClick={enem}>Move randomly</button>
    </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main  />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking deeply into this, it looks like your useEffect is continually adding event listeners and never removing them on cleanup. This looks like a memory leak to me.

This may help:

https://www.roundthecode.com/front-end-development/react/how-to-use-onclick-onmouseover-async-events-react

Comment: it doesn't start to lag when the useEffect runs and continually adding event listeners, It lags when the enem() function is continously pressed

Comment: enem() runs setState which rerenders your component which runs the useEffect on every render b/c there's no dependency array which adds another event listener which never gets cleaned up. I think this is a memory leak.

Comment: Also, the template literal for enemy.left is invalid. It needs backticks instead of double quotes:     const enemy = { 
    zIndex: "-1",
    borderRadius: "20%",
    width: "30PX",
    height: "30PX",
    backgroundColor: "green",
    position: "absolute",
    left: "${change}px",
  };